# Alert Me Not Sending to Distribution List Email

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom-list, alert, outlook

**Scenario:** I want to send Alert Me notification emails to a Outlook 365 distribution list.

**Problem:** I created send to email workflows in SharePoint designer and emails are sent to the distribution list fine.  But when I setup an Alert Me to send to the distribution list the initial setup email is sent but nothing after a new item is added to the list.

**Things done:** checked the outlook settings to make sure that it accepted all users and no authentication is required.

If the distribution email inbox receives the custom designer workflows and the initial Alert Me setup email, why doesn't it get any alerts when an item is added to the list? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have provided a read permission to the DL in your current site as the following

- Open your site > Site Setting > Users and Permission > Site permission.
- Click on Grant Permission > Add the distribution list email with at least read permission.

---

**Other Workarounds**

- **From SharePoint Sites.**

  - Create a custom alert workflow! (As you did).
- **From Outlook.**

  - Set the Alert for a specific SharePoint account, then in outlook, build a rule to forward the Alert email to the distribution list email!